# I want to access a my custom domain without using https

Tags: http, google-app-engine, ssl, https, hsts

I want to access a custom domain without using https.
I want to access 'http://my_domain.com'

Delete the 'secure' or change it to 'never' in app.yaml , but it will be redirected to 'https' without permission.

Comment: Try using explicit port 80 to connect, like `http://my_domain.com:80`.

Comment: Thank you, but don't access.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `HSTS`, so it is impossible to establish a non-secure connection.